# Conditionally formatting a date to show text if null in Access

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

My form displays a date field. However I've been instructed that the date field cannot be empty or null. Therefore if there is no date the field must show "N/A". The column is a Date format so I can't put the text into the table. My solution was to conditionally format in on the form. So I tried:

```
=IIf(IsNull([MyDate]),"N/A",[MyDate])
```

However this errors as a circular reference. Is it possible to display (I don't need to store) text conditionally if the column is Null? Whilst also maintaining the ability to edit and add a date?

Comment: You need to create a textbox and use your `IIF()` in it. You cannot use the `[MyDate]` control field and put your expression into it's ControlSource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Nz()` Like so

```
Me.myDate.value = Nz([MyDate],"N/A")
```

Although if the text Box is formatted then this will not work as `N/A` will not match a Date Format. Also when you say cannot be empty or Null then this sounds like it should be a database constraint with either a default value or the inability to save the record unless this is filled in.